# Is there a way to check if data exists then insert the data? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to know how to insert data when the data exists on the table. On the other hand, if the data does **not** exists then it will not be inserted. Is there a way to do this?

My View

```
<?php echo form_open('students/find_class   ') ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="studId" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Class Code:</h5>
            <small><li>Only teachers shall give you code</li></small><br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Enter class code to join" name="code" required />
                            
       </div>
        <hr>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Join Class</button>
</form>
```

My Controller which will connect through the Model

```
public function find_class(){
    $this->student_model->find_class();

    redirect('students/home');

}
```

Finally, My Model

```
public function find_class(){

    $data = array(
        'student_id' => $this->user_id,
        'code' => $this->input->post('code')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('classes', $data);
}
```

Comment: Please add a PHP logic to check if data exists before inserting logic. No other way!

Answer (score 0):

only this sql code:

```
INSERT INTO table (value1, value2, value3)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT value1_content, value2_content, value3_content) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT value1 FROM table WHERE value1 = value1_content
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.